# Trying to add new node in Cloudera Manager

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

I am trying to add new node to my cluster using Cloudera Manager. While adding new node it is asking me upload key. Which key i need to upload rsa of new node or rsa of Cloudera Manager or private key of Cloudera Manager

Answer (score 0):

When adding new nodes to the cluster through Cloudera Manager, the Cloudera manager needs to install software such as Cloudera agent on the new hosts. Thus it requires you to enter root or a username which has passwordless sudo privilege. Also you need to enter the password or upload a key which is a pem file containing the private key of that **new host**. For example, if you run this in AWS, this should be the private key that you save when launching the new ec2 instance.